# Continuation Monad - Int and String

Tags: haskell

[The Mother of all Monads](http://blog.sigfpe.com/2008/12/mother-of-all-monads.html) article presents this code:

```
ex3 = do
  a <- return 1
  b <- ContT (\fred -> "escape")
  return $ a+b
```

Then I can execute it:

```
ghci> runContT ex3 show
"escape"
```

But I can't run:

```
ghci> runContT ex3 id

<interactive>:51:14:
    Couldn't match type ‘[Char]’ with ‘Integer’
    Expected type: Integer -> [Char]
      Actual type: Integer -> Integer
    In the second argument of ‘runContT’, namely ‘id’
    In the expression: runContT ex3 id
```

How does `return $ a+b` type-check?

What's going on in `runCont ex3 show`? How about `runCont ex3 id` - it looks like it can't take `Int + [Char]` - but why did it compile?

Comment: I would start by checking the types of `ex3`, `runContT` and `runContT ex3` in GHCi.

Comment: The error tells you precisely, the `runContT` function is expecting a function of type `Integer -> String`, but you've provided it a function of type `Integer -> Integer`.  My guess is that this comes from the `ContT (\fred -> "escape")` line, since that is a function `Integer -> String`.  Change `\fred -> "escape"` to `\fred -> 1` and see if the type error goes away.

Answer (score 1):

First, let's see how `Cont` is defined:

```
data Cont r a = Cont {runCont :: (a -> r) -> r}
```

If you zoom in onto this declaration, you will see that `Cont` wraps a function that, given a function `(a->r)` produces `r`. In other words, it "hides" a value of type `a` (or `r`) "inside" `runCont`. So the presence of `Cont (\fred -> "escape")` (`fred` is a function, and is ignored) in the `do` expression tells us that `r` is `String`, and `runCont` of the entire expression is fixed to return a value of type `String`, and can only accept a function of type `a->String` for some `a`, which we'll need to work out.

Now let's see what `return` is like:

```
instance Monad (Cont r) where
    return x = Cont ($ x)  -- given a function, pass x to it
    (Cont m) >>= f = -- f :: a -> Cont r b, which roughly means
                     -- f :: a -> (b->r) -> r
                     -- which would roughly be Cont (\g -> m (flip f g))
                     -- notice we pass f to m: f is the stuff that needs
                     -- executing when m needs to; f is continuation of m
                     let h g x = let (Cont n) = f x -- unwrap (b->r)->r
                                 in n g
                     in Cont (m . h)
    -- or Cont (\g -> m (($ g) . runCont . f)), if that's easier to read
```

Notice how `>>=` works. If `m` does not use the function passed to it - remember, `runCont` may "hide" the value of type `r` directly, not necessarily the value of type `a` - then the "continuation" (`fred` in `Cont (\fred -> "escape")`) is not invoked, and you will observe "escape".

So, `a <- return 1` means `a :: Integer`, and clearly, `b <- Cont (\_ -> "escape")` does not mean `b :: String` - instead, `b` may be of any type - function `fred` passed to `Cont` is ignored, so any function returning `String` will work - but the type of `b` is fixed by the remainder of the expression. `return $ a + b` simply means `Cont String Integer` - since `a` is `Integer`, so `b` is fixed to be `Integer`, too.

Also, observe that by definition `show` in `runCont ex3 show` is destined as the continuation of the last line of the `do` expression: it is meant for the line `return $ a+b`, so you are meant to pass the function of type `Integer -> r` because `a+b` is `Integer`, and you are meant to pass a function of type `a -> String` because `r` is fixed by the expression `b <- Cont (\_ -> "escape")`.

The whole expression then is equivalent to the following:

```
do
  a <- return 1
  b <- Cont (\_ -> "escape")
  return $ (a+b)
==
  return 1 >>= (\a -> (Cont (\_ -> "escape") >>= (\b -> return (a+b))))
== -- apply return rule
  Cont ($ 1) >>= (\a -> (Cont (\_ -> "escape") >>= 
                        (\b -> Cont ($ (a+b)))))
== -- apply >>= rule
  Cont (\g -> ($ 1) (($ g) . runCont . (\a -> (Cont (\_ -> "escape") >>= 
                                              (\b -> Cont ($ (a+b)))))))
== -- apply >>= rule
  Cont (\g -> ($ 1) (($ g) . runCont . (\a -> (Cont (\h -> 
        (\_ -> "escape") (($ h) . runCont . (\b -> Cont ($ (a+b)))))))))
== -- (\_ -> x) y == x
  Cont (\g -> ($ 1) (($ g) . runCont . (\a -> (Cont (\h -> "escape")))))
== -- marking unused variables with "_" for clarity
  Cont (\g -> ($ 1) (($ g) . runCont . (\_ -> (Cont (\_ -> "escape")))))
== -- ($ y) (\_ -> x) == x
  Cont (\g -> ($ g) $ runCont (Cont (\_ -> "escape")))
== -- runCont (Cont x) == x
  Cont (\g -> ($ g) (\_ -> "escape"))
== -- ($ y) (\_ -> x) == x
  Cont (\_ -> "escape")
```